# Sorting NSMutableDictionary in Swift 3

Tags: swift, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

```
let dict1:NSMutableDictionary = ["no": "10", "name": "Joy"  ,"age":39]
let dict2:NSMutableDictionary = ["no": "33", "name": "Lily" ,"age":30]
let dict3:NSMutableDictionary = ["no": "19", "name": "Candy","age":22]
var arrPoint = [Any]()
arrPoint.append(dict1)
arrPoint.append(dict2)
arrPoint.append(dict3)
```

---

**how to sort by the no of elements?**

**Result as below:**

```
no = 10 , name = Joy
no = 19 , name = Candy
no = 33 , name = Lily
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort it using:

```
arrPoint = arrPoint.map { $0 as! NSMutableDictionary }.sorted { Int($0["no"] as! String)! < Int($1["no"] as! String)! }
```

As you can see there's a whole lot of mess going on in the closures. I have to first convert everything in the array to `NSMutableDictionary`, convert the string that I got from the key `"no"` to an integer and compare. There are obviously better ways.

If you can, make a struct. Maybe call it `Employee`? (You seem to creating dictionaries of employees, each of them has an age, a name, and a number)

```
struct Employee {
    var age: Int
    var name: String
    var number: Int
}
```

Then you can just create `Employee` arrays and sort them like this:

```
array = array.sorted { $0.number < $1.number }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift at all. Use Swift native types:

```
let dict1 : [String:Any] = ["no": "10", "name": "Joy"  ,"age":39]
let dict2 : [String:Any] = ["no": "33", "name": "Lily" ,"age":30]
let dict3 : [String:Any] = ["no": "19", "name": "Candy","age":22]

var arrPoint = [[String:Any]]()

arrPoint.append(dict1)
arrPoint.append(dict2)
arrPoint.append(dict3)
```

No sort the array with the `sort` function

```
arrPoint.sort(by: { ($0["no"] as! String) < $1["no"] as! String })
```

However I'd recommend also to use a custom struct like in Sweeper's answer.

Comment: **First of all, don't use NSMutableDictionary in Swift at all. Use Swift native types:** Any specific reason?

Comment: Yes, `NSMutable...` collection types don't provide type information and are not related to Swift collection types and you get mutability for free with the `var` keyword